# Combing two input flat files in SSIS

Tags: import, ssis, flat

I have two flat file inputs of the following format:

File 1-

```
AccountNumber1    Data1
AccountNumber1    Data2
AccountNumber1    Data3
AccountNumber2    Data1
AccountNumber3    Data1
```

File 2-

```
AccountNumber1    OtherData1
AccountNumber1    OtherData2
AccountNumber2    OtherData1
AccountNumber2    OtherData2
AccountNumber3    OtherData1
```

I need to apply a transformation that achieves the following:

```
AccountNumber1    Data1
AccountNumber1    Data2
AccountNumber1    Data3
AccountNumber1    OtherData1
AccountNumber1    OtherData2
AccountNumber2    Data1
AccountNumber2    OtherData1
AccountNumber2    OtherData2
AccountNumber3    Data1
AccountNumber3    OtherData1
```

That is to say, I need all of the account rows to stay together.  The Union task doesn't seem to be able to accomplish what I need because I have to maintain the arbitrary sort order of the first file and simply insert file 2's rows where the account numbers match.  Is there a way to accomplish this without a script task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Derived Column for both sources to add a column of 1s to the first and a column of 2s to the second table:

Table1:

```
 AccountNumber1  ,  Data1 , 1

 AccountNumber1  ,  Data2 , 1

 AccountNumber1  ,  Data3 , 1

 AccountNumber2  ,  Data1 , 1

 AccountNumber3  ,  Data1 , 1
```

Table2:

```
 AccountNumber1  ,  OtherData1 , 2

 AccountNumber1  ,  OtherData2 , 2

 AccountNumber2  ,  OtherData1 , 2

 AccountNumber2  ,  OtherData2 , 2

 AccountNumber3  ,  OtherData1 , 2
```

Now, first Use Union All, and then use Sort by AccountNumber and DerivedColumn in order.